# Auto-incrementing PLACEHOLDER value?

Tags: mysql, sql, auto-increment

I have the following `INSERT` statement:

```
INSERT INTO mytable (id, name) VALUES (%s, %s)
```

Sometimes I will have the `id`, but other times I will not and just want the id to autoincrement. Is there a way to do this without writing two different statements, for example, a special value (such as is done for the time value `NOW()`) to designate to use the auto-incrementing value

Comment: You can insert `NULL`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff thanks -- `0` works too -- want to post that as an answer and I'll accept it?